# how to change charcter - with / in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

In the bash script, suppose I have a string val `my_str="model-id"`, I want to replace character `'-'` with character `'/'`. How to do that?

I tried the following way, but it doesn't work:

```
echo "$my_tsr" | tr - /
```

Can some one tell me how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: The variable name is misspelled.  ```echo "$my_str" | tr - /```

Comment: `echo "${my_str//-//}"` may be more efficient

Answer (score 3):

```
my_str="model-id"
new_str=${my_str//-//}
echo "$new_str"
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240743/discussion-between-robin-sage-and-wjandrea).